# Помогите написать скрипт , который бы при потере фокуса на инпуте, проверял его содержимое на правильное количество символов

Tags: javascript

Сколько символов должно быть в инпуте, указывается в его атрибуте data-length.
Если введено подходящее количество, то outline инпута становится зеленым, если неправильное - красным.
Для добавления стилей, используй CSS-классы valid и invalid.

```css
#validation-input.valid {
  outline: 3px solid #4caf50;
}

#validation-input.invalid {
  outline: 3px solid #f44336;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="validation-input"
  data-length="6"
  placeholder="Введи 6 символов"
/>
```

У меня просто ступор на этом не могу понять даже с чего начать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("validation-input").onblur = function() {
  console.log(this.value.length);
  if (this.getAttribute('data-length') > this.value.length) { 
    this.classList.remove('valid');
    this.classList.add('invalid');
  } else {
    this.classList.remove('invalid');
    this.classList.add('valid');
  }
};
```

```css
#validation-input.valid {
  outline: 3px solid #4caf50;
}

#validation-input.invalid {
  outline: 3px solid #f44336;
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="validation-input"
  data-length="6"
  placeholder="Введи 6 символов"
/>
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь я бы так не додумалась наверное)

Comment: я вас отблагодарила)

Comment: @hzybodska там возле голосовалки гдето есть галка которая говорит что ответ принят, если ответ вам и правда помог, будьте добры тыкнуть ету галку )

Comment: сделала отметку)

Comment: @hzybodska пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict'

const elem = document.querySelector('#elem');

elem.addEventListener('blur', func);

function func() {
    if (String(elem.value).length != elem.dataset.length) {
        alert(32)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Version" content="BETA">
  <meta name="Autor" content="Евгений">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/schoolSite/logo/school.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>programming training</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="elem" data-length="5">
  <script src="/js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]